# How do you emphasize a word or a few ones in dialogue?

Tags: style, emphasis

I want to emphasize the words "Like ever" in the sentence below. Is this the correct way?

> We are celebrating one of my friend’s most important moments. Like ever.

Comment: I'd emphasise just 'ever' here ... by putting it in italics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is one allowed to use capitalization for emphasis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133643/is-one-allowed-to-use-capitalization-for-emphasis)

Comment: Italics? I have never used it in that way before. Are the periods at the end of the sentence correct?

Comment: "Like ever" is not a sentence. This question is going to be the same in any language, so I'm going to pass it over to Writing.

Comment: see also https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/59504/how-can-i-flavour-quote-only-dialogue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Characters' tone/pitch in dialogue](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/61143/characters-tone-pitch-in-dialogue) -- see in particular [Amadeus answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/61150/28528)

Comment: Using a separate sentence for emphasis like this is mentioned in the answers to [Different ways to emphasize](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/40897/34330), among other techniques.

Comment: How do you emphasize a word or a few ones in speech? Writing is just a poor representation of spoken language, which is far more complex than 26 letters allow.

Comment: "We are celebrating one of my friend’s most important moments. Like ever." uses a sentence fragment after a declarative sentence, a device in itself adding a staccato effect (the pause of the full stop) and often punch. Few object nowadays to the use of fragments in speech or dramatic writing. Here, I'd emphasise 'ever' in speech, and signify this in writing by using italics.

Comment: "I hate *migrating* questions. OP doesn't even have an account activated on this sub-stack, and probably isn't getting notifications." - - -  See how I emphasized **migrating** on the sentence above?